# Finding the expected value of a random function X that counts the number of pairs of consecutive zeroes for a random bit string of length n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

For example X(00100) = 2, X(00000) = 4, X(10101) = 0, X(00010) = 2. My understanding of expected value is that it is the product of the number of trials and the probability success will occur. I am guessing the number of trails will be 2^n, however I am not quite sure how to find the probability of the occurrence of two consecutive zeros.

Comment: You have $~n~$ digits that are each either $~0,~$ or $~1~$, with equal probability.  The problem may be routinely attacked via [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).  The cited article includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not 
independent of each other.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.